# Returns the value in the next empty rows

Tags: talend

**Input**
Here is an example of my input.

| Number | Date | Motore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 1 |
| 2 |  | Motore 2 |
| 3 |  | Motore 3 |
| 4 |  | Motore 4 |
| 5 | Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 1 |
| 6 |  | Motore 2 |
| 7 |  | Motore 3 |
| 8 |  | Motore 4 |

**Expected Output**

| Number | Date | Motore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 1 |
| 2 | Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 2 |
| 3 | Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 3 |
| 4 | Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 4 |
| 5 | Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 1 |
| 6 | Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 2 |
| 7 | Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 3 |
| 8 | Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2021 | Motore 4 |

I tried to use the TmemorizeRows component but without any result, the second line is valorized but the others are not. Could you kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a simple tMap with 2 inner variables (using the "var" array in the middle of the tMap)
Create two variables :

- currentValue : you put in it the value of your input column date (in my example "row1.data").
- updateValue : check whether currentValue is null or not : if null then you do not modify updateValue field . If not null then you update the field value. This way "updateValue" always contains not null data.

In output, just use "updateValue" variable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm testing the solution you proposed but I don't understand why I'm still getting the empty rows back, yet the reasoning doesn't make a crease

Comment: are you sure that the input is really null ? (could be an empty string for example, and in updateValue i test only if the field is null

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much. The field was not null but empty